# How to select an ng-options

Tags: angularjs

i've this code:

```
<select name="myname" ng-model="mymodel" 
ng-options="option.Id as option.Text for option in options.valuesO track by option.Id" ng-selected=""></select>
```

Option must be selected according a scope variable set in controller.
How i can do it?

Comment: what you need is in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Please provide a more complete example, and what the issue is.  Is this code throwing some kind of error?

Comment: you have to use ng-model="myselectedvalue" and then on $scope.myselectedvalue = 10;

Comment: Thanks peterpeterson. I tried your solution but doesn't work...

Comment: what is mymodel ?.. could you post your controller

Comment: mymodel is the scope variable that i set every time in my controller

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, set `$scope.mymodel=$scope.options.values0[0];` and you can delete `ng-selected` or you can set it to `mymodel`.